# Feed Reports from ASP .NET API to an ASP .NET Core app

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to feed reports to my asp net core application using a simple Web API in .net framework? Since there's basically no solution for reportings in ASP .NET Core and we rely mostly on Crystal Reports, I was wondering if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit difficult that if you directly reference asp.net web api in asp.net core due to the framework between asp.net and asp.net core is completely different .

If you want to create reports in ASP.NET Core , you could try a third party solution as a supported product:

https://www.syncfusion.com/reporting-tool/aspnet-core/report-viewer

And not quite sure about your report output format, if you try to generate PDF output, as alternative you may use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (command line tool) to for this purpose , you could refer to [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2153588.aspx?AspNetCore%20Reporting) for more details.

Another [discussion](https://forums.asp.net/t/2141178.aspx?Dynamic%20reports%20in%20MVC%20Core%202%200) on the report in asp.net core ,you also could refer to .